# Cannot link a static library using CMake

Tags: cmake, static-libraries

I have the following project structure.

```
<root
  CMakeLists.txt
  <exec_folder
    CMakeLists.txt
    ...
  <lib_folder
    CMakeLists.txt
    ...
```

In exec_folder I've got a CLI executable, so by purpose the target created in a additional directory.

**exec_folder** CMakeLists.txt

```
...
add_executable (foo ...)
target_link_libraries(foo bar)
```

**lib_folder** CMakeLists.txt

```
...
add_library(bar ...)
```

And now I've got `...cannot open file 'XXX.lib'` error.
Usually I use `add_subdirectory` when library directory nested into the main one, but now they are on the same level.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here because you don't show what is contained in root CMakeLists.txt. But based on the statement made that you didn't use `add_subdirectory()` for the library you need to make the following change.

The root CMakeLists.txt needs to contain both:

```
add_subdirectory(exec_folder)
add_subdirectory(lib_folder)
```

Otherwise bar will not be built and `target_link_libraries(foo bar)` will just search for some random `bar.lib`.  If the error is actually `XXX.lib` you've got bigger problems.